# Как по кнопке удалить несколько записей из таблицы?

Tags: jstl, jdbc, java-ee, java

У меня происходит вывод значений таблицы `MySQL` c помощью `JSTL`:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${client}">
 <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${row.id}">
    <c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.lname}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.otch}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.phone}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.adress}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.position}"/></td>

 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

И мне надо добавить кнопку удаления записей (т.е. передать отмеченные checkbox'ы и удалить записи). Каким образом можно это сделать? Спасибо.

**UPD.**

Вот метод удаления:

```
public void removeClient(HttpServletRequest req) throws SQLException {
        Client client = new Client();
        String[] chBox = req.getParameterValues("id");
        conDb();
        if(req.getParameter("delete")!= null) {

    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM clients WHERE id_clients=?");
    stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id")));
    stmt.executeUpdate();

    if(stmt != null) 
        stmt.close();
    if(con != null)
        con.close();
  }     
}
```

но все равно не получается удалить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, добавить кнопки в группу, с группы попросить все выделенные, с выделенных - значения, значения в запрос к БД для удаления.

Попробуй "этим всем" удалить какой-то реальный айди, подставь сам, то что можно удалить, посмотришь, где не работает точнее =)

Comment: Спасибо. Все получилось!)))